# Selecting my own answers in data explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to select all my own answers (stackoverflow) in data explorer.

I can't find any "help" page, and my sql-skills are limited...

Someone care to get me started?

(My goal is to select all my posts containing images (contains `<img`).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
SELECT Id, Score, Body, CreationDate 
FROM   Posts
WHERE  OwnerUserId = 276052  --your SO id
   AND PostTypeId=2  -- answers
   AND Body LIKE '%<img%'  --post body contains "<img"
```

​[Query on SEDE](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/628/search-a-users-answers)